# How can I inform the Zoom button of Mac OSX about best fit size for a web site

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

Mac os-x offers a little green orb of a button in lieu of the windows maximize that is a staple in the windows world.  Apparently this button is suppose to resize the window to a "best fit"  In the case of our web site, it's not doing that.  Is there a setting of some kind that we can use to inform the mac browser of the appropriate size to view our pages.

Comment: So I'm not the only one trying to do exactly this... good to know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked for a good way to do just that, and after a lot of searching I've concluded that it's not possible at all. There is no way to give this indication to Safari, although it would be wonderful. Maybe a bugreport to Apple is in order?

PS: as for all negative answers, it's hard to bring definitive proof... although I'd be more than happy to be proven wrong by someone else! Please do!